# error al intentar ejecutar una notificacion con ng-snotify

Tags: angular, angular5, notificaciones, notification

Usando [***esta librería***](https://artemsky.github.io/ng-snotify/documentation/essentials/getting-started.html)

Ejecute el comando:

> npm install ng-snotify

Agregue el **css** al ***angular.json***:

> "node_modules/ng-snotify/styles/material.css",

Mi ***app.module.ts***:
- lo importe así:

> import { SnotifyModule, SnotifyService, ToastDefaults } from 'ng-snotify';

- lo declare en los **import** así:

> SnotifyModule,

- también lo agregue a los **providers**:

> providers: [
>     { provide: 'SnotifyToastConfig', useValue: ToastDefaults},
>     SnotifyService
>   ],

En mi **ts**:

- lo importo así:

```
import { Snotify, SnotifyService } from 'ng-snotify';
```

- en el constructor lo declaro así:

```
private service: SnotifyService
```

- intento llamar una notificación con una función así:

```
showSuccess() {
  console.log('showSuccess');
  this.service.success('Example body content', 'Example Title');
}
```

Pero esto no me muestra nada en pantalla. Nada, solo la impresión por consola, pero nada de notificación, ni un error. ¿Por que?

Comment: Suena bastante obvio pero tengo que preguntar, ¿Estás poniendo en el template `<ng-snotify class="{{style}}"></ng-snotify>`? No lo mencionas en tu descripción del problema.

Comment: @Angel no lo vi en las guías que conseguí. Efectivamente es la solución. Mil gracias.

Comment: No viene dentro de las guías. Es un ejemplo dentro de gitHub, de ahí que en la documentación no lo pongan. (Que me parece algo importante)

Comment: @Angel muy importante, ejemplo, para novatos como yo. Gracias por la ayuda hermano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solo falta agregar en el html `<ng-snotify class="{{style}}"></ng-snotify>` según el ejemplo que tienen [aquí](https://github.com/artemsky/ng-snotify/blob/master/example/app/app.component.html).